# how to make my jquery reload after submitting data in Laravel Livewire?

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-livewire

i have table like this

[image]

but, after the submit, the highlighted row disappear and i cannot use the functionality of the highlighted row (jquery)

[image]

here is the jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            // Your initial highlighting the last row
            var table = $('#transaksiKasir tr:last');
            table.addClass('bg-slate-700 text-white active');

            $('body').on('keydown', function (e){

                // Take this values for every arrow key press
                if(e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 38){
                var table = $('#transaksiKasir tbody tr');
                var table_row = $('#transaksiKasir tr.text-white');
                }
                // Down
                if(e.keyCode == 40){
                    // Stop at the last row
                    if(table_row.index() == table.length - 1) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    
                    table_row.removeClass('bg-slate-700 text-white active');
                    table_row.next().addClass('bg-slate-700 text-white active')
                }
                // Up
                else if(e.keyCode == 38){
                    // Stop at the first row
                    if(table_row.index() == 0) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    
                    table_row.removeClass('bg-slate-700 text-white active');
                    table_row.prev().addClass('bg-slate-700 text-white active');
                }
            });
```

how to make the jquery reload after submit ?

Update :

this is my code right now, but after the submit data it can only move to the first and the last row of the table

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
            Livewire.hook('element.updated', (el, component) => {
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    // Highlighting the last row initially
                    var table = $('#transaksiKasir tr:last');
                    table.addClass('bg-slate-700 text-white active');
                
                    // Event handler for keydown on the body
                    $('body').on('keydown', function(e) {
                        // Get all table rows and the currently highlighted row
                        var tableRows = $('#transaksiKasir tbody tr');
                        var highlightedRow = $('#transaksiKasir tr.text-white');
                
                        // Down arrow key
                        if (e.keyCode == 40) {
                            // Stop at the last row
                            if (highlightedRow.index() == tableRows.length - 1) {
                                return false;
                            }
                
                            // Remove highlighting from current row and highlight the next row
                            highlightedRow.removeClass('bg-slate-700 text-white active');
                            highlightedRow.next().addClass('bg-slate-700 text-white active');
                        }
                        // Up arrow key
                        else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
                            // Stop at the first row
                            if (highlightedRow.index() == 0) {
                                return false;
                            }
                
                            // Remove highlighting from current row and highlight the previous row
                            highlightedRow.removeClass('bg-slate-700 text-white active');
                            highlightedRow.prev().addClass('bg-slate-700 text-white active');
                        }
                    });
                });
            })
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event to a browser using `dispatchBrowserEvent()`, as in the following example:

```
public function submit(){
   // your code
   $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('myEvent');
}
```

and in your js:

```
window.addEventListener('myEvent', event => {
    //your jquery code
})
```

For more information, please see: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events

Additionally, you can use the Livewire hook, like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    Livewire.hook('element.updated', (el, component) => {
       // your jquery code
    })
});
```

For more information, please see: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/lifecycle-hooks